# Html5 video set to browser full screen - same as noborder for flash movie

Tags: html, video, html5-video, fullscreen

I'm trying to set a html5 video to full browser size. I could do it but not as i want.

I did it before using flash using "Scale" equal to "noborder". This is the result: http://inoq.com/lxgo/transportes.html - click on the right menu, a popup will open with the video.

I want to do the same using HTML5 video. I could set it full browser size, but keeps showing the black bars on top and bottom or left and right, depending on screen size, to keep the ratio. This is the result: http://inoq.com/lxgo2/cidade.html

Any ideas on how to do it? Is it possible at all?

Thanks
Bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the HTML5 `video` element, scaling one of the dimensions causes the other to automatically scale to maintain the aspect ratio. As such, if you set the `height` of your `video` element to the `height` of the `window`, and centre it within a containing `div` with `overflow` set to `hidden`, you should get the effect you're looking for.

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="container">
        <video id="player" autoplay loop>
          <source src="http://inoq.com/lxgo2/videos/transtejo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="http://inoq.com/lxgo2/videos/transtejo.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="http://inoq.com/lxgo2/videos/transtejo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    // Using jQuery for ease
    var $player = $('#player');
    var $window = $(window);

    // if you only set one of width and height, the other dimension is automatically 
    // adjusted appropriately so that the video retains its aspect ratio.
    // http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/        
    $player[0].height = $window.height(); 

    // centre the video 
    $player.css('left', (($window.width() - $player.width()) / 2) + "px");
```

**CSS:**

```
  #container { 
      position: absolute; 
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%; 
      overflow: hidden; 
  }

  #player { 
      position: absolute; 
  }
```

Comment: Please take a look at my response.

Comment: Ask a new question mate, you're much more likely to get a response.